# jest-puppeteer / expect-puppeteer: [object Object] is not supported

Tags: jestjs, puppeteer

I am writing very simple automatic tests with jest-puppeteer and I cannot get expect-puppeteer to accept the puppeteer object. I am new at jest and jest-puppeteer so perhaps I am missing something obvious.

The test:

```
import expectPuppeteer from 'expect-puppeteer'

describe("(context)", () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.goto(process.env.URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
  });

  it('should be titled "Google"', async () => {
    await expect(page.title()).resolves.toMatch('Google');
  });

  it('should have an img', async () => {
    await expectPuppeteer(page).toMatchElement('img', {})
  });
})
```

Error:

```
● undefined › should have an img

    [object Object] is not supported

      23 |
      24 |   it('should have an img', async () => {
    > 25 |     await expectPuppeteer(page).toMatchElement('img', {})
         |           ^
      26 |   });
      27 | })

      at expectPuppeteer (node_modules/expect-puppeteer/lib/index.js:105:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/lab_wk4.test.js:25:11)
```

It appears that the `page` object is a `CDPPage`:

```
    CDPPage {
      eventsMap: Map(1) { 'pageerror' => [ [Function: handleError] ] },
      emitter: {
        all: Map(1) { 'pageerror' => [Array] },
        on: [Function: on],
        off: [Function: off],
        emit: [Function: emit]
      }
    }
```

but inside `expectPuppeteer` (the function which fails) the `type` of the object is not found: it is `null`. Also I can't find any documentation of this object, but it seems to be a valid Puppeteer page so I don't see why it wouldn't be accepted.

For completeness, my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-puppeteer",
  resolver: "./resolver.js",
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!w3c-html-validator|chalk)"
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in jest-puppeteer which happens with puppeteer 18. It's being tracked here: [#495](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer/issues/495)

To fix the issue simply downgrade to latest 17x version with `npm install puppeteer@17.1.3`

Comment: Hej - 
I had the same issue - the page.response object was CDPPage. Downgrading puppeteer to 17.1.3 solved the issue. However, I'm wonderung why it is still present - I was testing with puppeteer 19.0.2.